# IOS: Passing value from UITableView row to UILabel in First Controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, static, uilabel

In my second controller when user select a row and after clicked on the back button

I would like to update a UILabel with the text choice.

I have added a UILabel on the first controller and connected to h. file but I don't know how go on

```
 I would like to replicate the GENERAL/AUTO-LOCK function in iPhone/iPad Settings.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use delegates for this.

SecondViewController.h:

```
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate;

@interface
...
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
...
@end

@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)secondViewController:(SecondViewController *)vc didTapRowWithText:(NSString *)text;
@end
```

SecondViewController.m:

```
@implementation
...
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self.delegate secondViewController:self didTapRowWithText:cell.yourLabel.text];
}
...
@end
```

whoever created and pushed SecondViewController (and maybe/hopefully also 1st one):

```
// put this after secondViewController initialization
secondViewController.delegate = self;

- (void)secondViewController:(SecondViewController *)vc didTapRowWithText:(NSString *)text
{
    firstViewController.yourLabel.text = text;
}
```

Comment: Last part in FirstController i have some doubts.....i have to implement PrepareForSegue...now i'm using connection in storyboard

Comment: didnt know that you're using storyboards.. but normally you can set a storyboard id for the controller and access the controller through this id in code, as far as i know.

Comment: THANK YOU. AFTER PUTTING AN ID FOR PUSH FOR SEGUE IN STORYBOARD ALL WORK GOOD

Comment: You're welcome! I really appreciated it, would be nice if you could accept the answer and give me an up vote for that :-)